# Ionic 2 - Alertcontroller animation

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I want to display an alertcontroller dialog from top to bottom while opened it and do reversing while closing it. Is that possible?

I tried the below code but no luck.

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Warning',
      cssClass: 'alertCtrlfade ',
      message: "This is not a correct form",
      enableBackdropDismiss: false,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Ok',
          cssClass: 'alert-btn',
          handler: (data: any) => {

          }
        },]
    });

    alert.present();
```

### In app.css

```
.alertCtrlfade {
  transform: translate3d(0, 100, 0) !important;
 }
```

Is that any way we can achieve this animation in alertcontroller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a Toast notification.

check this link out and see if it's what you wanted [ToastControllerAPI](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toast/ToastController/)

> Edit : Added some code for reference

in the typescript file

```
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular'; 

@Component({
templateUrl: 'example.html'
})

 constructor(private toast: ToastController) {
 }

 exampleToast() {
  let exampleNotification = this.toast.create({
  message: 'This is not a correct form',
  showCloseButton : true,
  closeButtonText : 'Ok',
  position: 'top'
  }); exampleNotification.present();

 }

}
```

This gives off the effect that you were looking for and can be used to replace AlertController.

Comment: No, not looking for toast controller.